# Animation of accordion content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an accordion and trying to add transition effect whenever the user tries to click on the accordion header.

I added `height: auto` and `transitiion` to the accordion container, but this effort seems useless here.

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
[].slice.call(texts).forEach(function (text) {
    text.onclick = function () {
        text.parentElement.classList.toggle('animate');
    }
});
```

**[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vuor3oo/3/)**

PS: the height of each content differs and the animation should happen while opening and closing the content.

**EDIT**:

I tried the possible duplicate question solution, which isn't animating perfecting,

http://jsfiddle.net/9vuor3oo/5/

The animation works only while opening the accordion but not closing it. and also the last accordion doesn't even animate on opening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

Comment: @Amit this isn't solving the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/9vuor3oo/4/

Comment: I marked it as duplicate because the essence of the question is the same: animating CSS `height: auto` (impossible). The fact that it's not working for you is irrelevant and you need to post a new question or modify your current question to show the problem without `height: auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your sample: http://jsfiddle.net/9vuor3oo/6/. You need to add the `max-hight` to `.parent .child` and then add transition to that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I understand the concept. :)